# Parameters in class name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I pass parameters to a class name from a function?

```
   funcName = (param) => {
   return (<div className='param'>
   ..............
   </div>) }
```

Comment: Do you mean to set parameters programatically?

Comment: You can use `{}` and use any JavaScript expression you like, e.g. `const funcName = (props) => <div className={props.param}> ... </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{}` to inject JS code in the JSX layout:

```html
<div className={my_parameter}>
```